# ValueError: `validation_data` should be a tuple `(val_x, val_y, val_sample_weight)` or `(val_x, val_y)`. Found: <__main__.Generator object at>

Tags: python-3.x, keras-2

I know that got asked already a few time but no answer fit my bill.

I have a csv file with text (newspaper content) and label, column 0 and 1.

I am trying to write my first custom generator for text classification but getting the error

```
ValueError: `validation_data` should be a tuple `(val_x, val_y, val_sample_weight)` or `(val_x, val_y)`. Found: <__main__.Generator object at 0xd376a6e80>
```

Here is the class

```
class Generator(object):

    def __init__(self, data_file):
        self.data_file = data_file
        self.length = -1

    def __iter__(self):
        while True:
            with open(self.data_file, 'r') as f:
                reader = csv.reader(f)
                for row in reader:
                    yield row[0], row[1]

    def __len__(self):
        if self.length ==  -1:
            n_rows = 0
            with open(self.data_file, 'r') as f:
                reader = csv.reader(f)
                for row in reader:
                    n_rows += 1
            self.length = n_rows
        return self.length
```

I also tried it with `yield row[0], row[1]`, as well `return`. Neither worked.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error until I made my Generator class inherit the methods from keras.utils.Sequence (see [fit_generator documentation](https://keras.io/models/sequential/)). You can try this:

```
import keras

class Generator(keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, data_file):
        self.data_file = data_file
        self.length = -1

    def __iter__(self):
        while True:
            with open(self.data_file, 'r') as f:
                reader = csv.reader(f)
                for row in reader:
                    yield row[0], row[1]

    def __len__(self):
        if self.length ==  -1:
            n_rows = 0
            with open(self.data_file, 'r') as f:
                reader = csv.reader(f)
                for row in reader:
                    n_rows += 1
            self.length = n_rows
        return self.length
```